# Angular Firebase How to find and retrieve data by field

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have datas on realtime Database on firebase with the following structure :

```
    {   "tests" : [ {
           "description" : "55",
           "number" : "11",
           "serie" : "0"   }, {
           "description" : "22",
           "number" : "13",
           "serie" : "0"   }, {
           "description" : "Test",
           "number" : "55",
           "serie" : "2"   
} ]
```

And I want tro retrieve all my data where the field "serie" are equal to "0".
I have a methode in my service component for retrieving all the tests data, like this :

```
  getTests(){
    firebase.database().ref('/tests')
      .on('value',(data: DataSnapshot)=>{
        this.tests= data.val() ? data.val():[];
        this.emitTests;
      }
    );
  }
```

At this time I do not know how retrieving only datas where serie is equal to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do that by using a Firebase Database query:

```
firebase.database().ref('/tests')
  .orderByChild("serie").equalTo("0")
  .on('value',(data: DataSnapshot) => {
    data.forEach((child: DataSnapshot) => {
      console.log(child.key, child.val());
    });
```

As you can see a query in Firebase has two steps:

1. You order the data, either on a child property or on its key of value.
2. You then filter the data based on what you ordered on.

Also see the Firebase documentation on [ordering and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).

Comment: This command works but only when the child "serie" is equal to zero. So it returns and array, but if my id is different, it returns an object. The structure is different, for zero I have an array without the id of each of object, and for other value each show its id then the child.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean there. I added a loop to my answer just in case that's what you're struggling with. If that isn't it, or you can't get it to work, post the code you tried, and the output, typically in a similar format to what I use.

Comment: I have create a new question for my problem. Thanks for your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57069933/firebase-orderbychild-return-the-first-time-an-array-the-second-time-an-objec